# Java DynamoDB Back-end gives an InvalidSignatureException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am a software intern, and I'm working on Java back-end to query a dynamoDB table. We are currently in the process of changing to a new table format. The new table has a business key and a sort key, unlike previous which only used a business key. The following is the method to query the table:

```
public String getCommuterOptions(String crewID) throws JsonProcessingException {
           String hashKey = crewID;
           String rangeKey = "E";
           CommuterOptionsRequest response = dynamoDBMapper.load(CommuterOptionsRequest.class, hashKey, rangeKey, 
DynamoDBMapperConfig.TableNameOverride.withTableNameReplacement(applicationProperties.getProfileTableNm()).config());
           return ServiceUtil.convertErrorObjectToJson(response, "Success");
}
```

Note, the range key for this query needs to be "E".

When I run the application, the following error results:

```
    "Unable to unmarshall exception response with the unmarshallers provided (Service: 
AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidSignatureException; Request ID:
6LVEKJAFGBBPM3NB7U4LE60P13VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)"
```

Has anyone seen this before? I have tried an alternative way of querying the table using .query() and get the same error. I have double checked things such as system time, and secret key and access key with no success. The old controller is very similarly designed, except for this method, and works perfectly. Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.330</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>-->
</dependencies>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I updated the dependencies, and also got new access and secret keys. This along with a slight change to the DTO's annotations for hash and range key fixed the issues. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Can you successfully make *any* DynamoDB API calls e.g. to list tables or describe a given table (some action/resource for which you have permission)? Was this code working prior to the schema change and your updated query code?

Comment: Move to V2 if possible. V1 not Amazon recommended anymore

Comment: Jarmod, Thanks for the response. I just tried this with listing tables, and it threw the same error.

Comment: This means you depedencies are messed up. How are you adding them to your project?

Comment: @smac2020 I'll be honest, this project was set up by someone else. I only just got to it in its current state, except for the controller I mentioned above which I added. I will look into this and update here

Comment: You can now see the project's dependencies in the main post. It's also worth noting I am using Maven

Comment: I normally do not run V1 - I will look at this to see If i can spot an issue

Comment: See update in my answer - I updated the V1 dep in my POM and a V1 call worked

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, and it now changed from an InvalidSignatureException to a ValidationException. I'm going to try some changes to my model class and update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the very old AWS SDK for Java V1, which is not best practice when using Java to query data from an Amazon DynamoDB table. (**AmazonDynamoDBv2** is still part of V1)

The recommended way to query data is to use the **AWS SDK for Java v2**.

You can read about this SDK in the **AWS Java V2 Developer Guide** here:

[Working with DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-dynamodb.html)

If you do not know how to use this SDK, read the [Quick start](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html) section that talks about tasks that you need to do such as setting up your creds, etc.

You can query data using these methods.

1. Using the DynamoDbClient
2. Using the Enhanced Client
3. Using PartiQL - uses a SQL type syntax.

All of the below Java examples are part of **AWS SDK for Java v2**. You can find these code examples and many other Amazon DynamoDB code examples in the official AWS Github repo:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/dynamodb

**Using the DynamoDbClient to Query data**

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.query.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.QueryRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.QueryResponse;
import java.util.HashMap;
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.query.import]

/**
 * Before running this Java V2 code example, set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see the following documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 *
 *  To query items from an Amazon DynamoDB table using the AWS SDK for Java V2,
 *  its better practice to use the
 *  Enhanced Client. See the EnhancedQueryRecords example.
 */
public class Query {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String usage = "\n" +
            "Usage:\n" +
            "    <tableName> <partitionKeyName> <partitionKeyVal>\n\n" +
            "Where:\n" +
            "    tableName - The Amazon DynamoDB table to put the item in (for example, Music3).\n" +
            "    partitionKeyName - The partition key name of the Amazon DynamoDB table (for example, Artist).\n" +
            "    partitionKeyVal - The value of the partition key that should match (for example, Famous Band).\n\n" ;

       if (args.length != 3) {
           System.out.println(usage);
           System.exit(1);
       }

       String tableName = args[0];
       String partitionKeyName = args[1];
       String partitionKeyVal = args[2];

       // For more information about an alias, see:
       // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html
       String partitionAlias = "#a";

       System.out.format("Querying %s", tableName);
       System.out.println("");

       ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
       Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
       DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
           .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
           .region(region)
           .build();

       int count = queryTable(ddb, tableName, partitionKeyName, partitionKeyVal,partitionAlias ) ;
       System.out.println("There were "+count + "  record(s) returned");
       ddb.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.query.main]
    public static int queryTable(DynamoDbClient ddb, String tableName, String partitionKeyName, String partitionKeyVal, String partitionAlias) {

        // Set up an alias for the partition key name in case it's a reserved word.
        HashMap<String,String> attrNameAlias = new HashMap<String,String>();
        attrNameAlias.put(partitionAlias, partitionKeyName);

        // Set up mapping of the partition name with the value.
        HashMap<String, AttributeValue> attrValues = new HashMap<>();

        attrValues.put(":"+partitionKeyName, AttributeValue.builder()
            .s(partitionKeyVal)
            .build());

        QueryRequest queryReq = QueryRequest.builder()
            .tableName(tableName)
            .keyConditionExpression(partitionAlias + " = :" + partitionKeyName)
            .expressionAttributeNames(attrNameAlias)
            .expressionAttributeValues(attrValues)
            .build();

        try {
            QueryResponse response = ddb.query(queryReq);
            return response.count();

        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return -1;
    }
    // snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.query.main]
}
```

**Using the Enhanced Client to Query data**

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.query.import]

import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbEnhancedClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.DynamoDbTable;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.Key;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.TableSchema;
import software.amazon.awssdk.enhanced.dynamodb.model.QueryConditional;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException;
import java.util.Iterator;
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.query.import]

/*
 * Before running this code example, create an Amazon DynamoDB table named Customer with these columns:
 *   - id - the id of the record that is the key
 *   - custName - the customer name
 *   - email - the email value
 *   - registrationDate - an instant value when the item was added to the table
 *
 * Also, ensure that you have set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

public class EnhancedQueryRecords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build();

        DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
            .dynamoDbClient(ddb)
            .build();

        String result = queryTable(enhancedClient);
        System.out.println(result);
        ddb.close();
    }

    // snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.query.main]
    public static String queryTable(DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient) {

        try{
            DynamoDbTable<Customer> mappedTable = enhancedClient.table("Customer", TableSchema.fromBean(Customer.class));
            QueryConditional queryConditional = QueryConditional.keyEqualTo(Key.builder()
                .partitionValue("id101")
                .build());

            // Get items in the table and write out the ID value.
            Iterator<Customer> results = mappedTable.query(queryConditional).items().iterator();
            String result="";

            while (results.hasNext()) {
                Customer rec = results.next();
                result = rec.getId();
                System.out.println("The record id is "+result);
            }
            return result;

        } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return "";
    }
    // snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.mapping.query.main]
 }
```

**Using the PartiQL to Query data**

```
package com.example.dynamodb;

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.partiql.import]
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.ExecuteStatementRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.ExecuteStatementResponse;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.partiql.import]

/*
 * Prior to running this code example, create an Amazon DynamoDB table named Music as discussed in this topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-gettingstarted.html
 *
 * You must also have set up your development environment, including your credentials.
 *
 * For more information, see this documentation topic:
 *
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html
 */

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.java2.partiql.main]
public class DynamoDBPartiQ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ProfileCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = ProfileCredentialsProvider.create();
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .region(region)
            .build();

        AttributeValue att1 = AttributeValue.builder()
            .s("Acme Band")
            .build();

        AttributeValue att2 = AttributeValue.builder()
            .s("PartiQL Rocks")
            .build();

        List<AttributeValue> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
        parameters.add(att1);
        parameters.add(att2);
        queryTable(ddb, parameters);
    }

    public static void queryTable(DynamoDbClient ddb, List<AttributeValue> parameters ) {

        // Retrieve an item from the Music table using the SELECT PartiQL statement.
        ExecuteStatementResponse response = executeStatementRequest(ddb, "SELECT COUNT(SongTitle) FROM Music", parameters);
        processResults(response);

        //Update an item in the Music table using the UPDATE PartiQL statement.
        processResults(executeStatementRequest(ddb, "UPDATE Music SET AwardsWon=1 SET AwardDetail={'Grammys':[2020, 2018]}  where Artist=? and SongTitle=?", parameters));

        //Add a list value for an item in the Music table.
        ExecuteStatementResponse resp2 = executeStatementRequest(ddb, "UPDATE Music SET AwardDetail.Grammys =LIST_APPEND(AwardDetail.Grammys,[2016])  where Artist=? and SongTitle=?", parameters);
        processResults(resp2);

        // Add a new string set attribute for an item in the Music table.
        processResults(executeStatementRequest(ddb, "UPDATE Music SET BandMembers =<<'member1', 'member2'>> where Artist=? and SongTitle=?", parameters));

        // Add a list value for an item in the Music table.
        processResults(executeStatementRequest(ddb, "UPDATE Music SET AwardDetail.Grammys =list_append(AwardDetail.Grammys,[2016])  where Artist=? and SongTitle=?", parameters));

        // Remove a list value for an item in the Music table.
        processResults(executeStatementRequest(ddb, "UPDATE Music REMOVE AwardDetail.Grammys[2]   where Artist=? and SongTitle=?", parameters));

        // Add a new map member for an item in the Music table.
        processResults(executeStatementRequest(ddb, "UPDATE Music set AwardDetail.BillBoard=[2020] where Artist=? and SongTitle=?", parameters));

        // Add a new string set attribute for an item in the Music table.
        processResults(executeStatementRequest(ddb, "UPDATE Music SET BandMembers =<<'member1', 'member2'>> where Artist=? and SongTitle=?", parameters));

        // Update a string set attribute for an item in the Music table.
        processResults(executeStatementRequest(ddb, "UPDATE Music SET BandMembers =set_add(BandMembers, <<'newmember'>>) where Artist=? and SongTitle=?", parameters));
        System.out.println("This code example has completed");
    }

    private static ExecuteStatementResponse executeStatementRequest(DynamoDbClient ddb, String statement, List<AttributeValue> parameters ) {
        ExecuteStatementRequest request = ExecuteStatementRequest.builder()
            .statement(statement)
            .parameters(parameters)
            .build();

        return ddb.executeStatement(request);
    }

    private static void processResults(ExecuteStatementResponse executeStatementResult) {
        System.out.println("ExecuteStatement successful: "+ executeStatementResult.toString());
    }
}
```

// snippet-end:[dynamodb.java2.partiql.main]

**UPDATE**

I updated my V1 POM to use this:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.239</version>
 </dependency>
```

THIS V1 Code worked:

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.ResponseMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.GetItemRequest;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Get an item from a DynamoDB table.
 *
 * Takes the name of the table and the name of the item to retrieve from it.
 *
 * The primary key searched is "DATABASE_NAME", and the value contained by the field
 * "Greeting" will be returned.
 *
 * This code expects that you have AWS credentials set up per:
 * http://docs.aws.amazon.com/java-sdk/latest/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html
 */
public class GetItem
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                String table_name = "Customer"; //args[0];
                String name = "id101" ; //args[1];
                String projection_expression = null;

                // if a projection expression was included, set it.
                if (args.length == 3) {
                        projection_expression = args[2];
                }

                AmazonDynamoDB ddb =  AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();


                System.out.format("Retrieving item \"%s\" from \"%s\"\n",
                        name, table_name);

                HashMap<String,AttributeValue> key_to_get =
                        new HashMap<String,AttributeValue>();

                key_to_get.put("id", new AttributeValue(name));

                GetItemRequest request = null;
                if (projection_expression != null) {
                        request = new GetItemRequest()
                                .withKey(key_to_get)
                                .withTableName(table_name)
                                .withProjectionExpression(projection_expression);
                } else {
                        request = new GetItemRequest()
                                .withKey(key_to_get)
                                .withTableName(table_name);
                }

                 try {
                        Map<String,AttributeValue> returned_item = ddb.getItem(request).getItem();
                         ResponseMetadata metadata = ddb.getCachedResponseMetadata(request);
                         System.out.println("The request ID is "+metadata.getRequestId());


                        if (returned_item != null) {
                                Set<String> keys = returned_item.keySet();
                                for (String key : keys) {
                                        System.out.format("%s: %s\n",
                                                key, returned_item.get(key).toString());
                                }
                        } else {
                                System.out.format("No item found with the key %s!\n", name);
                        }
                } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
                        System.err.println(e.getErrorMessage());
                        System.exit(1);
                }
        }
}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I am just an intern and don't have control over whether we upgrade to V2 or not. :(

Comment: I understand - but this old SDK is not best practice anymore.